# How do I delete / remove a file

Tags: command-line, delete, rm

I am a beginner with Linux / Ubuntu, and I'm trying to remove / delete a file.

The specific is a wallet I created in Electrum to import a paper wallet; I can see the wallet in the file list but can't delete it.

I do understand that one uses the `rm` command in the Terminal, but I am not sure how to word the actual command. The file I'm trying to delete is `home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/import key`, but but if I type that into the Terminal it is rejected - i.e.

```
rm home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/importkey
```

is rejected.

Comment: Try `rm -rf home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/import key`

Comment: Try `rm -rf home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/import\ key`

Comment: Both of you are missing the / before home.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mind the space! That tells "rm" there will be a 2nd file after the 1st one.

And since it is 1 file you need to take care of the space. What will work:

```
rm /home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/"import key"
```

or

```
rm /home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/import\ key
```

by "escaping" the space or

```
rm /home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/import{tab}
```

(keep hitting tab til it shows the file name).

`/home/duncan` can be abbreviated by `~` (ie. `rm ~/.electrum/wallets/"import key"`)

---

The file name was Import_keys. So the shorthand version for Duncan:

```
rm ~/.electrum/wallets/Import_keys
```

No need for "'s. The capital I probably was the culprit.

Comment: Thank you very much - I do appreciate your kind help and the time you have given up to help.  MUCH appreciated!  Duncan (Scotland)

Comment: @Duncan As you're new to the site, if you are happy with this answer then please accept it by clicking the grey tick to the left of it.

Comment: Thanks - did not know about that Carl - will do after this.  After replying to you I found that I can't get it to work - get this message:

Comment: ..... get this message: "rm: cannot remove ‘home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/import_keys/import_keys’: No such file or directory".  Can you suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: and when i try the other option i get: "duncan@duncan-HP-Compaq-dc7900-Small-Form-Factor:~$ rm ~/.electrum/wallets/"import_key"
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/import_key’: No such file or directory" .  Once again, many thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Duncan you typed an underscore between "import" and "key" but you should have typed a space.

Comment: that is how the folder and file are named; i.e. the folder is "Import_keys" and the file it contains (that I wish to delete) is "Import_keys".  Sorry to hassle you. Many thanks, Duncan

Comment: could it be something to do with the fact that I have an additional hard drive - a Samsung SSD?  So, in the filing directory I see both "Computer" and "Samsung SSD" at the same level - i.e. one can chose to work in one or the other.  I see the file that I want to delete is on the "Computer" but the Terminal seems to be on the "Samsung SSD" and I don't know how to change them.

Comment: No @Duncan It has to be with you not being correct. 1. Linux is CAse SenSitive. "Import Key" is NOT "import key". And you did not include a _ in your question. It states a "space".And you are also forgetting the leading / several times. I would advice to use the {tab} auto complete so the system itself fills in the chars.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind.  Will try all you suggest.  This is difficult for a 66 year old!  Thanks once again for your patience.  I am now going to try:  "rm ~/.Electrum/Wallets/Import_keys/"Import_keys"

Comment: Still not working - my latest try is:  -- rm /home/duncan/.electrum/wallets/import_keys/"Import_keys" -- but this still does not work.  Not easy this coding stuff....  By the way, sorry for not including the underscore in my original posts - but it is in the file and folder name.

Comment: VICTORY !  Have managed to do it Rinzwind (and others) this is what did the trick:  rm ~/.electrum/wallets/"Import_keys"    Once again, many, many thanks for your help and patience - VERY much appreciated!  Duncan (Scotland)

Comment: @Duncan - You would be well served to go through a few bash tutorials or search up Ubuntu Terminal tutorials on youtube.  It won't take long for you to get comfortable at the terminal. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Many thanks for the advice - will do that. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help and suggestions.  Sincerely appreciated.