# Deleting folders from directory which does not contain .txt files within it

Tags: command-line

`/dir/grouped` is my path. Under `grouped` folder I have two types of files in general ( files which contains `.txt` files and files which don't contain it). For example

- `/dir/grouped/file1` contains .txt file
- `/dir/grouped/file2` does not contain .txt file

I want to remove file2 (because it does  not contain .txt file) from grouped. How can I do this from the terminal.

Comment: Are you saying `file1` ha extension `.txt`? That it is actually `file1.txt`?

Comment: Files that contain files? Are you talking about archives, like tar or zip? Or do you mean directories that contain files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete / remove a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716751/how-do-i-delete-remove-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `man find`, `man xargs`, `man sed`, `man uniq`. I'd solve your problem like this:

1. Produce a list of ALL the directories. The ones you want to delete are on this list.
2. Produce a list of all directories containing `'*.txt'` files. For simplicity, I'll assume the `'*.txt'` filenames do NOT contain blanks.
3. Subtract the two lists, giving the list of directories not containing `'*.txt'` files.
4. Pass this list to `echo rm -rfv`. (Remove the `echo` when you're happy)

Here's one way:
**WARNING** I have executed parts of this as Proof-of-Concept, but have **NOT** done an End-to-End test.

```
# --depth imposes a bottom-up order
find /dir/groupd --depth -type d --print >/tmp/alldir.tmp

# 'sed ...' changes '/dir/groupd/file1/foo.txt' to
#                    '/dir/groupd/file1'.
# and `uniq` keeps only one, no matter how often '/dir/groupd/file1'
# is generated.
find /dir/groupd --depth --type f -name '*.txt' --print | \
    sed -e 's%/[^/]*$%%' | \
    uniq >/tmp/txtdir.tmp 
# 
grep -E -v -f /tmp/txtdir.tmp /tmp/alldir.tmp >/tmp/nontxtdir.tmp
# inspect /tmp/nontxtdir.tmp, or
xargs </tmp/nontxtdir.tmp echo rm -rfv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with all Bash features, plus `rm`:

```bash
root='/dir/grouped'
# Make globs null if there's no match.
shopt -s nullglob
# For each dir in the root dir
for dir in "$root"/*/; do
    # Get array of .txt files.
    files=("$dir"*.txt)
    # If the array is not empty
    if [[ ${#files[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Contains .txt files: $dir"
        echo rm -rfv "$dir"  # Remove 'echo' when done testing.
    else
        echo "Does not contain .txt files: $dir"
    fi
done
```